# Comparing a distribution of percentages

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, population, percentage

I have two populations that I would like to compare, each of which contains N samples. Each sample itself contains many events that can be categorized into 20 different, mutually exclusive, categories. These are expressed as percentages but could be expressed by raw counts. The percentages of each row (sample) sum to 100%.

I would like to be able to determine if the *populations* are different/distinct based on the distributions associated with each sample. Thanks for you advice.

Example of how the data is organized:

```
Population 1:
SampleName, Category1, Category2, Category3, ... Category20
Sample1, 0.04, 0.09, 0.20, ... 0.07
Sample2, 0.14, 0.09, 0.10, ... 0.00
Sample3, 0.08, 0.19, 0.24, ... 0.03
...
SampleN, 0.04, 0.64, 0.02, ... 0.17

Population 2:
SampleName, Category1, Category2, Category3, ... Category20
Sample1, 0.03, 0.07, 0.21, ... 0.00
Sample2, 0.05, 0.03, 0.10, ... 0.30
Sample3, 0.17, 0.59, 0.14, ... 0.03
...
SampleN, 0.34, 0.24, 0.12, ... 0.07
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, this sounds like a *multinomial logisitc regression* problem. The wikipedia page on the subject can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression).

Basically, the log-odds between the different categories are modeled as a linear function of your independent variables (in your case, just a binary variable identifying which population the subject is a member of) separately, and then these are all used to construct the multinomial likelihood, which is then maximized, like when doing traditional generalized linear models.

For a more in depth/statistical walkthrough of multinomial regression, I suggest these [notes](http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c6.pdf) which are publicly available from a Princeton University professor's course website.